# jQuery validate text input fields

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using SquareBit shortlist to add items to an order form. Once added the visitor can update the quantity.

Items added to the form output this:

```
<form name='shortlist_form' id="order" method='POST' >
    <div class="order-item"><h3>Game Birds -&nbsp; Cleaners Disinfectants prod1</h3>
        Qty: <input type="text" name="extra:qty[130]" value="57" />
    </div>
    <div class="order-item"><h3>Pigs -&nbsp; Platinum Programme prod1</h3>
        Qty: <input type="text" name="extra:qty[131]" value="25" />
    </div>   
    <div class="order-item"><h3>Game Birds -&nbsp; Cleaners Disinfectants prod2</h3>
        Qty: <input type="text" name="extra:qty[132]" value="8" />
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Update" />
```

I'm having trouble validating. I don't know how to stop the extra: qty[item_id] field from being empty.

As a starting point I'm using this validation code. I need to be able validate each extra: qty field.

```
$("#order").validate({
    //set this to false if you don't what to set focus on the first invalid input
    focusInvalid: false,
    //by default validation will run on input keyup and focusout
    //set this to false to validate on submit only
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    //by default the error elements is a <label>
    errorElement: "div",

    //place all errors in a <div id="errors"> element
    errorLabelContainer: $("#errors"),

    rules: {
       "extra:qty[]": {
            required: true,
       }
    },
    messages: {
        "extra:qty[]": {
            required: "Please enter a quantity",
        },
    }               
});
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have any inputs on the screen that do not need input? otherwise you could just validate on input fields rather than trying to figure out their id's, or just give them a class when you generate them and then validate on that class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:-

```
$('[name*="extra:qty"]').each(function(){
   $(this).rules('add', {
    required: true,        
    messages: {
        required: "Please provide entry"          
    }
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/429/)